# Trying to select rows and include first 2 distinct non-null values from 4 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [Test].[dbo].[MyTest]
(
[Id]    INT NOT NULL,
[ColA]  VARCHAR(255) NULL,
[ColB]  VARCHAR(255) NULL,
[ColC]  VARCHAR(255) NULL,
[ColD]  VARCHAR(255) NULL
);
```

And let's say I have:

```
Id     ColA     ColB     ColC     ColD
---------------------------------------
1       A        B        NULL     C
2       A        A        NULL     D
3       NULL     A        B        NULL
4       B        B        B        B
5       NULL     NULL     NULL     NULL
```

What I'm trying to do is select every row from this table, but only want the first 2 distinct non-null values from ColA-ColD, in order. In other words, If for one row ColA & ColB are both non-null and are distinct from each other, those are the 2 that I want for that row. Using the data I gave above, the wanted results from this query would be:

```
1, A (from ColA), B (from ColB)
2, A (from ColA), D (from ColD)
3, A (from ColB), B (from ColC)
4, B (from ColA)
```

Notice that if all data for ColA-D for a row is NULL that row is not selected. Also it's ok if there is only 1 non-null distinct column (you can see from result row with Id 4) - it doesn't have to be 2, but ideally it would be 2.

Basically I would ideally be able to get the TOP(2) DISTINCT from ColA-ColD WHERE none of those are NULL, but I realize TOP and DISTINCT work on rows, not on columns like I'm trying to do. Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be fastest with a CTE and a `CASE` statement:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id
          ,COALESCE(ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD) AS col1
          ,ColB
          ,ColC
          ,ColD
    FROM   tbl
    )
SELECT id
      ,col1
      ,CASE WHEN ColB <> col1 THEN ColB 
            WHEN ColC <> col1 THEN ColC
            WHEN ColD <> col1 THEN ColD
            ELSE                   NULL
       END AS col2
--    ,COALESCE(NULLIF(ColB, col1)
--             ,NULLIF(ColC, col1)
--             ,NULLIF(ColD, col1)) As col2   -- alt. syntax doing the same
FROM   cte
WHERE  col1 IS NOT NULL
ORDER  BY id
```

The first column returned (`col1`) is the first non-null column and the second column (`col2`) is the second distinct non-null value in that order. The `CASE` statement works, because `NULL <> value` never evaluates to `TRUE`.

If there is only one distinct value, `col2` returns `NULL`.
If all source columns are `NULL`, `col1` is `NULL` and the row is filtered by the `WHERE` clause.

The commented alternative syntax with `NULLIF()` is shorter, but I don't expect it to be faster.

Comment: You may want to say that `the second column is the second non-null value` - I initially thought your would include nulls (which would be distinct from an actual value).  And it's possible to filter out null-only rows in the cte.

Comment: @X-Zero: You've got a point, "distinct" in SQL parlance would include a `NULL` value. I clarified my explanation accordingly, thanks.

Comment: Brilliant! This should perform better than the many nested COALESCE statements (though I too had been starting to think about it in this route myself and really appreciate the answer there Mark). Thanks so much!!

Comment: @fogwolf: Cool. BTW, if Mark's answer was useful to you, you might want to press the "This answer is useful" button next to his answer. Hint! ;)

Comment: Ah, good to know. I've used StackOverflow for years not but so far all of my questions had been previously asked and answered, so I'm still new to posting. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your database design is not right.

Probably, you should not have `ColA,..,ColD` columns. It looks like you should have a second table with the `id`, `type` (A, .., D) and `value`.

With that structure you can *easily* come up with any output.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry for not including more context. This is part of a large process. There is a table that I'm mapping into where I do not have control over the schema. This process has multiple steps with a lot of temp tables, is handling a lot of data and has to perform. So I really can't iterate over each individual entity represented by "Id" and populate a table like you describe. I basically need to be able to do bulk inserts by selecting from one table into another and as I say, at this step I am selecting from a table with a similar schema to the temp table schema I give above.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select id,
       coalesce(ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD) Result1,
       coalesce(nullif(coalesce(ColB, ColC, ColD), coalesce(ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD)),
                nullif(coalesce(ColC, ColD), coalesce(ColB, ColC, ColD)),
                nullif(ColD, coalesce(ColC, ColD)) ) Result2
from [Test].[dbo].[MyTest]
```

Comment: This is close. I tried it, but if ColA is not null, for example, the data from there gets populated intooth Result1 and Result2. So this isn't quite covering the DISTINCT requirement. Thanks!

Comment: Not only that, but even if there is also data in ColB that is distinct from the data in ColA, the data from ColA is still being returned for Result1 and Result2.

Comment: @user1255182: Check again (this query was edited since I first posted it) - if ColA is not null, it gets populated into Result1, but ColA will **never** be populated into Result2. From the sample data supplied, I get the results (1, A, B); (2, A, D); (3, A, B); (4, B, NULL); (5, NULL, NULL).

Comment: Yep, just caught that. It seems right! I'll put it through the paces to make sure and follow up here if I see any problems but I think this is it. Thanks so much!!!